# Animation in Flutter: How to resize a Stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

What's the right way to animate a change in size of a `Stack` widget?

The first idea was to wrap the `Stack` with a `SizeTransition`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: _height, // Just a Tween<double>(begin: 200, end: 400)
          axis: Axis.vertical,
          axisAlignment: -1,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                left: 10,
                child: Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 10,
                right: 10,
                child: Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.green),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

But running the snippet causes the following error:

```
'package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 588 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.
```

So, apparently, that's not the right way to do it. Questions now is: How do you animate resizing of a `Stack`?

Wrapping the `Stack` with a `SizedBox` would fix the error message, but then, how do you get the size from `SizedTransition` to set the proper size of a `SizedBox`?

Comment: Have you considered using ```Hero``` widget ?

Comment: @Arijeet Thanks for the hint! I haven't tried the `Hero` widget yet. It looks like it could do the job, but it also feels a little hackish considering that it's meant to pass widgets across `PageRoute`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AnimatedContainer` as parent of `Stack` widget by providing `height` or `width` one you like to change over time.

```dart
AnimatedContainer(
  color: Colors.purple,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  height: height,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        bottom: 10,
        left: 10,
        child: Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.blue),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        child: Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.green),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```